# RE match and searching in python

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to scrape data from a text file now when i use

```
re.match('some pattern',source_string)
```

i get nothing in return but when i use

```
re.search('some pattern',source_string)
```

it returns this

`[<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x25ae238>]`

Now this is my problem how do i get to make the string searched that occurs in the file to be returned and what is that gibberish output that i get..please help me

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)? Easily readable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fine, it returns a `match` object. To get the string, just get the 0th group:

```
a = re.search('some pattern',source_string)
print a.group(0)
```

`re.match` will try to match the string from the start against your regex whereas `re.search` will search for the specified regex in the string. You should use `re.search` in this case.